# d3 stack on data without header

Tags: d3.js

My csv is dynamically generated and doesn't have any headers because the number of columns and rows are varying with each run. An example below

```
A, 30, 40, 35, 25
B, 25, 35, 45, 35
```

Which if there were headers would look like as below

```
   Age1, Age2, Age1, Age2
A,  30,   40,   35,   25
B,  25,   35,   45,   35
```

For each row the data is in pairs, i.e. col[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvxmL.png) & col[2] need to be stacked and col [3] & col [4] need to be stacked. Goal is to have a clustered stacked bar chart with A and B in X axis and two stacked bars for each pair.

[image]

I was trying to follow the example at https://bl.ocks.org/SpaceActuary/6233700e7f443b719855a227f4749ee5 but I am not able to get, how to use the stack function in the absence of headers/keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use d3.text to load the CSV data, and then iterate over the text to create an array of objects with named values, which could then be stacked or whatever you would normally do in D3 with your data

```
d3.text("data.csv", function(text) {

    console.log(text);

    var data = []

    d3.csvParseRows(text).forEach(function(row) {
      let obj = {}
        row.forEach(function(value, i) {    
        let pairIndex = Math.floor((i - 1) / 2)
        //assume first value is the index or name for the row, eg A, B, etc
        if (i == 0) { 
          obj.index = value 
        } 
        else if (i % 2 == 0) {           
          let v = "age2-" + pairIndex
          obj[v] = value
        } else {
          let v = "age1-" + pairIndex
          obj[v] = value
        }
      });
      data.push(obj)
    });

    console.log(data);
// continue with your code
```

Comment: So essentially create a data with header from the headerless data

Comment: yep - would make it easier to handle the data later on when joining to data etc.  But of course, there are other solutions to this problem :)